# Speeding up an update over multiple tables

Tags: postgresql

As you probably know, UPDATE INNER JOINS on postgres are not the best. I have gone back to the old way of updating across multiple tables but have come into some performance issues with the following query:

```
UPDATE table_a  a
SET    field1 = field4
FROM table_b b , table_c c 
WHERE a.field3 = b.field3 
AND a.field1  = c.field4
AND ((a.field1  Is Null) Or (a.field1 ='')) AND (a.field2 ='T');
```

Does anyone have a better/quicker way for running queries like this in postgres?

Edit: One of the joins are there to just ensure data is in that table, although I do not need it.

Comment: What is the purpose of table `c` in this update? Its values are never used, except for the `AND a.field1  = c.field4` (which could cause multiple `c` rows to match, causing multiple updates to `a.field1` ) BTW: does field4 in `SET    field1 = field4` come from the `c` table ?

Comment: @joop to validate it exists, so for the update to happen it must be in a,b and c i don't need to use any values just the join validates it has data in that table

Comment: try to replace the joins with `exists` conditions

Comment: It's hard to say anything about performance without any numbers or an explain plan.

Comment: Please read [postgresql-performance](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) then **[edit]** your question and provide the missing information.

Comment: There are several flaws in your query: 1) In your `WHERE`, when `a.field1 Is Null` then `a.field1 = c.field4` is always falsy (actually `NULL`), so that will never happen, so technically, your query checks for every row in `a`, there is a row in `c` which is `c.field4 = ''`. 2) Also, because `a.field1 = c.field4` is in `WHERE`, the `SET field1 = field4` will be a NOOP (actually just fires the UPDATE triggers, but doesn't change the data at all).